# How can i make random UILabel and ImageView in a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I want to make an UILabel with a specific CGAffineTransform and an UIImageView in a UIView. So far i have tried to make random view in the self but problem is some views are being outside of the screen.Here is my code so far i have done.

```
-(void)generateView {
   float viewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
   float viewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;

   int numViews = 0;
   while (numViews < 2) {
      BOOL goodView = YES;
      UIView *candidateView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random() % (int)viewWidth, arc4random() % (int)viewHeight, 200, 100)];
      candidateView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
      for (UIView *placedView in self.view.subviews) {
         if (CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInset(candidateView.frame, -10, -10), placedView.frame)) {
            goodView = NO;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (goodView) {
         [self.view addSubview:candidateView];
         numViews += 1;
      }
   }
}
```

Now at first my question is how can make all views in the self.view which frame will be in the self.view and Secondly If i want to make UIView with specific CGAffineTransform then how i can make it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first question:

```
UIView *candidateView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random() % ((int)viewWidth - 200), arc4random() % ((int)viewHeight - 100), 200, 100)];
```